# TypeScript: Warn about comparison by reference

Tags: typescript

Is there a way in TypeScript to mark a class as non-comparable, in a meaningful way, by reference? I'd like to get an error/warning if I accidently try to compare an object of that class using `==` or `===`, as this won't find "equal" clones.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Both `==` and `===` will only return true if both operands evaluate to the exact same object. This behavior cannot be overwritten.

Comment: If you mean "Can I make `a === b` an error?" where `a` and `b` are objects, then: It's hard to prove a negative, but I very much doubt it. After all, checking to see if you have the **same** reference in two places is a valid operation, you can't just say that `==`/`===` can't be used at all.

Comment: Separately, **no** objects in JavaScript (and thus TypeScript) can be compared in a meaningful way by reference, other than the meaning "are these the same object?'. JavaScript doesn't let you overload `==`/`===`, so `a === b` where `a` and `b` are objects will always compare references (that is, check to see they're the **same object**, not just equivalent objects).

Comment: So if you worry was that two different instances of the same class would be equal to each other according to `==`/`===` then the answer is that you don't have to worry about this because that will never be the case in JavaScript.

Comment: The answer to the question as stated is "no, TypeScript does not have a configuration to warn on object equality comparison". You might be able to write your own eslint rule to do that (I didn't see an existing one) but that's out of scope for the question as asked.  Does that fully address your question? If so I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @FelixKling I worry the opposite: I need to compare two instances regardless of their === equivalence. And thus I need to somehow forbid the === to avoid bugs.

Answer (score 2):

TypeScript does not have a feature to disable equality operators for object references. Remember that it's a valid operation (checking to see if two variables or similar contain a reference to the **same** object). While you might be able to prevent explicit `===` and `!==` operations by writing a lint tool plugin or similar, beware that these comparisons are often hidden (for instance, inside a call to `Array.prototype.includes`, or a `Map` or `Set` operation, or `Object.is`, etc.).

Anyone writing TypeScript code should be aware (or quickly learn) that you can't use equality operators for checking object *equivalence*, only for checking object *identity* (`if (a === b)` means "are they the *same object*", not "are they equivalent objects").

This isn't something that's at all limited to your class. It's true of all objects in JavaScript (and thus TypeScript):

```js
console.log({} === {});                   // false
console.log([] === []);                   // false
console.log(new Date(0) === new Date(0)); // false
// ...and so on...
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `===` to compare objects in Typescript is not an indication of a possible mistake in the same way it is in Java, for example. In Java, if you have two `Integer` objects that are being compared by `==`, it is very likely because you didn't realise they were boxed, or it might be because you thought they'd be auto-unboxed. The problem is that in Java, `==` can mean different things for different "integers" depending on what kind of integer they are, where normally the language does implicit coercions so you don't have to care what kind of integer you have.

Typescript does not have any similar semantics to that*, so the only reason a reader might suspect `===` means comparing by value in Typescript is because the reader is not familiar with Typescript. So it is very unlikely that the Typescript team would choose to add a warning to the compiler for this. Note that even in Java where the analogous code *is* very likely a mistake, the compiler doesn't warn you about it; that is relegated to third-party linting tools. It is probably possible to write a rule for [typescript-eslint](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint) which warns for it, but I wasn't able to find an existing rule for it.

<sub>* Javascript, and therefore Typescript, *does* actually have boxed numbers which you can create by writing `new Number(...)`, but unlike Java, there is no use-case for boxed numbers in Typescript, you should always use primitive numbers instead. I think linters *do* warn about using boxed primitives, because it's basically always bad to use them.</sub>

Comment: As a side-note - Java is even more tricky when it comes to boxed numbers because `n1 == n2` might actually produce `true` or `false` even if both are defined as `Integer.valueOf(someString)`. This is because for the lower integers (up to 128 or maybe 256 or so) are *cached* for performance reasons. So comparing two of the same cached instance is `true`. But larger numbers will be new instances on both sides, thus "not equal".